# Login to ASP.NET Core API application from mobile with facebook

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create a web api using Asp.Net Core MVC. The will login in the mobile device using the Facebook SDK, but I need to authenticate the user at the server site.
How could I do this right?

thnx